# Self-referential foreign key relationship on SQLAlchemy declarative mixin class with declared_attr

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, self-referencing-table

I have a mixin class that I define near the beginning of the SQLAlchemy app and then inherit on pretty much every declarative model I use.

```
class Owned(object):

    @declared_attr
    def created_by_id(cls):
        return Column(Integer, ForeignKey("accounts.id"),
            nullable = True)

    @declared_attr
    def created_by(cls):
        return relationship("Account", foreign_keys = cls.created_by_id)

    @declared_attr
    def updated_by_id(cls):
        return Column(Integer, ForeignKey("accounts.id"),
            nullable = True)

    @declared_attr
    def updated_by(cls):
        return relationship("Account", foreign_keys = cls.updated_by_id)
```

This works well for most intended use cases.

```
class Thing(Owned, Base): # Base is from SQLAlchemy's declarative_base()
    pass

account = session.query(Account).first()

thing = Thing(created_by = account, updated_by = account)

session.add(thing)
session.commit()
session.refresh(thing)

assert thing.created_by == account # pass
assert thing.updated_by == account # pass
```

However, I get unexpected behaviour when I define `Account` itself as inheriting from `Owned`.

```
class Account(Owned, Base):
    pass

account_old = session.query(Account).first()

account_new = Account(created_by = account_old, updated_by = account_old)

session.add(account_new)
session.commit()
session.refresh(account_new)

assert account_new.created_by_id == account_old.id # pass
assert account_new.updated_by_id == account_old.id # pass

# BUT!

assert account_new.created_by == account_old # fail
assert account_new.updated_by == account_old # fail

account_new.created_by # []
account_new.updated_by # []
```

I see that, in this case, I've turned `created_by_id` and `updated_by_id` into self-referential foreign keys. What I don't understand, however, is why SQLAlchemy isn't populating their associated `relationship` columns with the expected `Account` instances.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

In an [adjacency list relationship](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/self_referential.html) the "direction" is assumed by default to be one-to-many. Using the [`remote_side`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/relationship_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.relationship.params.remote_side) directive establishes that the relationship is many-to-one, which is what you're after:

```
def _create_relationship(cls, foreign_keys):
    kwgs = {}
    # Bit of a chicken or egg situation:
    if cls.__name__ == "Account":
        kwgs["remote_side"] = [cls.id]

    return relationship("Account", foreign_keys=foreign_keys, **kwgs)


class Owned:

    @declared_attr
    def created_by_id(cls):
        return Column(Integer, ForeignKey("accounts.id"),
            nullable = True)

    @declared_attr
    def created_by(cls):
        return _create_relationship(cls, cls.created_by_id)

    @declared_attr
    def updated_by_id(cls):
        return Column(Integer, ForeignKey("accounts.id"),
            nullable = True)

    @declared_attr
    def updated_by(cls):
        return _create_relationship(cls, cls.updated_by_id)
```

Comment: Thanks so much. I followed your approach and am getting this error: `sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: Relationship Account.created_by could not determine any unambiguous local/remote column pairs based on join condition and remote_side arguments.  Consider using the remote() annotation to accurately mark those elements of the join condition that are on the remote side of the relationship.` Do I have to specify the join manually? Or is it that `foreign_keys` is only being recognised in one direction?

Comment: Hmm, I think a bit more context would be in order. Given the 2 relationship attributes the mixin worked in my local tests and should not require any manual joins.

Answer (score 0):

Convenient solution would be using `@declared_attr.directive` decorator.

So, in your mixin class you can write something like following:

```py
@declared_attr.directive
def order(cls) -> Mapped[OrderTable | None]:
    return relationship(primaryjoin=f'{cls.__name__}.order_no==OrderTable.id')
```